# Different function call types with Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

How do they differ in terms of

- execution order
- exception handling
- return values

etc.

```
  getFromURL().then(function () {
      return callbackFunc();
    });
    
    getFromURL().then(function () {
      callbackFunc();
    });
    
    getFromURL().then(callbackFunc());
    
    getFromURL().then(callbackFunc);
```

Comment: They are *not* doing the same thing. #3 calls the callback function *before* the promise settles.

Comment: Also worth noticing that #3 will potentially cause an exception, unless `callbackFunc()` returns a function.

Comment: #1 and #4 are good patterns. #2 does not return the promise that `callbackFunc` might return, which would be a problem. #3 is the worst unless `calllbackFunc()` returns a function, in which case the other implementations are probably not doing what is intended.

Comment: edited, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are returning same results

That is not correct.  They are not all doing the same thing.

Your options #1 and #4 are reasonable ways to do things.  Your option #2 is probably wrong, particularly if `callbackFunc()` is asynchronous.  Your option #3 is always wrong unless `callbackFunc()` returns a function that you want to be called in the promise chain and you want it to be called before `getFromURL()` resolves (both of which are rare circumstances).

To see the difference between all of these, you need a return value from `callbackFunc()` and you need a second `.then()` so you can see that return value.

So, let's say that `callbackFunc()` returns "hello".  Then, here are what you get.  These two are identical:

```
getFromURL().then(function () {
  return callbackFunc();
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});

getFromURL().then(callbackFunc).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Both of these will log the return value from calling `callbackFunc()` or the resolved value from a promise returned by `callbackFunc()` (whichever it returns) or if `callbackFunc()` returns a rejected promise, then the promise chain will take on that rejection.  These two schemes are a normal way to do a promise chain where `callbackFunc()` is sequenced into the promise chain after `getFromURL()` resolves.

---

This one always logs `undefined`:

```
getFromURL().then(function () {
  callbackFunc();
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

because there's not return value from the first `.then()` handler.  `callbackFunc()` is called in the same sequence as the previous two, but since you aren't returning it's return value from the `.then()` handler, it is orphaned and separated from the promise chain and the promise chain has an `undefined` resolved value.

If `callbackFunc()` is asynchronous, then this is probably just wrong because `callbackFunc()` is not part of the promise chain and since you aren't returning it's promise from the `.then()` handler, there is no way to track its success or failure.  This becomes a "fire and forget" separate promise chain.  If it rejects, you will get a system error for an uncaught rejection.

If `callbackFunc()` is synchronous and you don't care about its return value, then this just sequences `callbackFunc()` after `getFromURL()` resolves like the previous two options except that you're ignoring the return value.

---

This one is most different from the others:

```
getFromURL().then(callbackFunc()).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

It will call `callbackFunc()` BEFORE `getFromURL()` resolves.  It's return value will be passed to `.then()`.  Unless that return value is a function reference, it will be entirely ignored by the promise chain.

Comment: very detailed answer thanks! sorry if the question was too broad.

Answer (score 0):

```
getFromURL().then(function () {
  return callbackFunc();
});
```

This statement returns a Promise which will resolve with the value returned by `callbackFunc()` (following any Promise chains if `callbackFunc` returns a Promise). This is a common pattern.

---

```
getFromURL().then(function () {
  callbackFunc();
});
```

This statement returns a Promise which resolves with undefined. If `callbackFunc()` is asynchronous, the outer Promise resolves before `callbackFunc()` finishes. Often this may be undesirable.

---

```
getFromURL().then(callbackFunc());
```

This statement calls `callbackFunc()` immediately, then passes whatever it returns to the `.then()`. Results undefined. No idea what it does without seeing `callbackFunc`. Might result in an error.

---

```
getFromURL().then(callbackFunc);
```

This statement returns a Promise which will resolve with the value returned by `callbackFunc()`. It is mostly identical to the first one and is totally acceptable.

Generally, #1 and #4 are what you'll want to use. #2 and #3 are either sloppy or wrong.